# Recursively move all TXT files in subdirectories to other directories based on filename

Tags: bash, scripts

I have a bunch of `TXT` files in a series of subdirectories that follow a naming scheme

```
-Incoming
  |-Office-August.2020
    |--Office-August.2020.txt
  |-Office-September.2020
    |--Office-September.2020.txt
  |-Office-October.2020
    |--Office-October.2020.txt
  |-Branch-August.2020
    |--Branch-August.2020.txt
  |-Branch-September.2020
    |--Branch-September.2020.txt
  |-Branch-October.2020
    |--Branch-October.2020.txt
```

I would like to write a script to periodically move all of the `TXT` files to a series of directories based on their filenames, e.g.:

```
-Documents
  |-Office
    |--Office-August.2020.txt
    |--Office-September.2020.txt
    |--Office-October.2020.txt
  |-Branch
    |--Branch-August.2020.txt
    |--Branch-September.2020.txt
    |--Branch-October.2020.txt
```

I'd then like to delete the old subdirectories and any additional left over files. I'm still learning bash scripting, so I'm not exactly sure how to accomplish this, but this is what I've come up with so far. It's finding the files, but isn't able to move them yet.

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT=~/Incoming
OUTPUT=~/Documents

find $INPUT -type f -name "*.txt" | while IFS= read -r filename; do
  case $filename in
    Office*)  mv "$filename" "$OUTPUT/Office/" ;;
    Branch*)  mv "$filename" "$OUTPUT/Branch/" ;;
    *) echo "don't know where to put $filename";;
  esac
done
```

Any suggestions?

**Edit**: I am able to move the files if I add an `*` to the beginning of the line `Office*)  mv "$filename" "$OUTPUT/Office/" ;;` in the case statement, because I realized that the filenames being read included the full path, rather than beginning with Office or Branch. Now the line reads `*Office*)  mv "$filename" "$OUTPUT/Office/" ;;`. So, now I'm wondering if there is a way to better write the `find .... | while ...` line to identify only the filename, not the full path.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use find command to find and copy all the files that founded.
2. The syntax is `find <PATH-OF-THE-FILES-TO-COPY> -iname <NAME> -exec cp {} <PATH-COPY-THE-FILES-TO> \;`

   - an example for command `find /home/xthudrsdayx/Office/ -iname *.txt -exec cp {} /home/xthudrsdayx/txt/ \;`
3. **Remarks:**

   - `-exec cp` is to exec the cp command on all the files that founded.
   - Asterisk (*) means any combination of ASCHII in the place you putted the *.
   - you can use many more filters of `find` command at`man find`.
4. Hope that was what you were looking for, if something not working or not understood please comment so we can try solve it together.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was already using the find command in third line of my script. The part where I was getting hung up was with using the `case` statement to sort the found pdfs into different directories, but I think I have that sorted out now..

Answer (score 0):

`basename $filename` strips off the path
So, for completeness put e.g.

```
mv `basename "$filename"`;;
```

in your `case`

Comment: Would `mv "$(basename "$filename")" ;;` also work?

Comment: @xthursdayx Yes but `command "${filename##*/}" ` is preferable

Answer (score 0):

`find -execdir` will change the directory to where the file was found before exec your command. Provided your files are well-formatted, you can use the beginning of the file `${2%%-*}` Office<s>-August.2020.txt</s> to build the destination directory.

```bsh
$ find Incoming/ -mindepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' \
  -execdir bash -c 'mkdir -p $1/${2%%-*}; mv -nt $_ $2' _ $PWD/Documents {} \;
                                                 ^      ^  ^             ^
           Last argument from the previous command      $0 $1            $2
```